# Create two different instances of ERC-721 in the same smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, nft, erc721

So I want to create two different kind of NFTs, each one with its own name, but I don't want to create two different smart contracts and duplicate my code.
I don't know if its possible, but it is worth asking.
Sorry if it's an stupid question.

```
constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol) ERC721(_name, _symbol)
```

I instantiate it like this, so maybe it could be posible to instantiate two of them? idk. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this question is difficult to understand, do you want to create two ERC721 smart contracts and merge them into one (so that you have **collection 1** and **collection 2** in **one contract**)?

if you mean this there are two answers, one long and one short.

the short answer: **you simply can't**

the long answer: starting from a basic ERC721 you can modify and above all add functions which refer to collection 1 and others to collection 2

but this would take you **out of the ERC721 standard**, with the risk that your contract will no longer be sure, but above all they would not be visible and interactable by non-expert users, having come out of the standard, no existing Dapp supports such a thing, you should create your own Dapp.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed to know

Answer (score 0):

When deploying the contract, you can just pass in a different name in the `string memory _name` field